# getListUi wire returns with 400 - ILLEGAL_QUERY_PARAMETER_VALUE

Tags: lightning-web-components, wire, lwc-wire-getlistui

I query opportunity records using list view developer name, which is used for getListUi. But sometimes, randomly, when I go to the records page, I get this error:

[image]

Here's the wire for getListUi:

```
@api objectName;
secondaryFields = ['LastViewedDate', 'LastReferencedDate']
selectedListView = '';

@wire(getListUi, {
    objectApiName: '$objectName',
    listViewApiName: '$selectedListView',
    optionalFields: '$secondaryFields'
})wiredRecords(result) {
    this.wiredResult = result
    if (result.data) {
        this.assignData(result.data.records.records)
    } else if (result.error) {
        this.error = result.error
        this.records = undefined
        this.showNoRecordsError()
    }
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: How are you using this component. From what I see in these snippets, the selectedListView attribute is empty and it's actually required for this wire adapter.

Comment: Of course, it is used, otherwise, I would get the error all the time.

Comment: Well we can only try to help with the context that is provided in the question. I suggest you provide a little more context and a little less snark.

Comment: In the documentation, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_get_list_ui, I dont see `optionalFields` as parameter for `getListUi`. May be because of that?